# CSRF protection prevents me from uploading a file

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, csrf

I created a simple app with Spring Boot and Spring security which contains :

- A login form
- An "upload" form (with an associated Controller on backend's side)

**Problem** : Spring security has built-in default CSRF protection. It works well with common REST calls but it prevents me from uploading a file : I get this error message :

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.

If I deactivate CSRF protection, I can successfully upload the file.

I created a [SSCCE](https://github.com/ArnaudDenoyelle/sscce-file-upload) to illustrate the problem. The steps to reproduce are :

1. Launch the application (Main class is `com.denodev.Application`)
2. Connect to `localhost:8080`
3. Authenticate with those credentials :

   - Login : `user`
   - Password : `password`
4. When redirected to the "upload" form, try to upload any file.
5. In class `Application`, feel free to activate/deactivate CSRF protection, restart the app and retry.

The relevant part of the code is :

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/upload-file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return "Successfully received file "+file.getOriginalFilename();
  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
  protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/", "/**/*.html", "login").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
          .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
          .and()

          //1 : Uncomment to activate csrf protection
          .csrf()
          .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
          .and()
          .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)

          //2 : Uncomment to disable csrf protection
          //.csrf().disable()
      ;
    }

    /**
     * Return HTTP 200 on authentication success instead of redirecting to a page.
     */
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
      return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
          httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
      };
    }

    /**
     * Return HTTP 401 on authentication failure instead of redirecting to a page.
     */
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
      return new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
          httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
          httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
        }
      };
    }

    /**
     * Return HTTP 403 on "access denied" instead of redirecting to a page.
     */
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
      return new AccessDeniedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
          httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
          httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
        }
      };
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
      return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
          httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
          httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
        }
      };
    }
```

**What I tried :**

The [Spring security's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipart) about Multipart advices to place `MultipartFilter` before Spring security. It explains well how to do it with a plain old webapp by editing the `web.xml` file. This is not applicable to Spring Boot and I cannot figure what is the equivalent syntax.

I tried to expose the `MultipartFilter` with annotations `@Bean` and `Order` with several options but I still struggle with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you send the uploaded file in an AngularJs HTTP request ?

Comment: @BillBilal In the context of this SSCCE, no, but I tried the same with Angular/AJAX call and get the same problem.

Comment: In my case, it works. I added a directive to upload the file in the client side, after that I send it in an AngularJs POST request. AngularJs adds the X-XSRF-TOKEN token to every HTTP request

Comment: Your example wouldn't work. You don't send the X-XSRF-TOKEN to the server as you do. This is how the CSRF protection is supposed to protect you.

Comment: Another solution is to add the CSRF token in the form that uploads the file (_csrf which is hidden) but I don't know if you will have to do some additional configurations.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

Add a directive to upload a file in the client side :

```
app.directive('fileModel', function ($parse) {

        return {

            restrict: 'A',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;

                element.bind('change', function(){

                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });

                });

            }
    };
})
```

Upload the file :

```
<input type="file" file-model="fileToUpload"/>
```

This is how I upload the file to the server :

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", fileToUpload);

$http({

        method: 'POST',
        url: 'the URL',
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        data: formData,
        transformRequest: angular.identity

})

.success(function(data, status){

})
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it seems to work thanks to `'Content-Type': undefined`. Isn't it a bad practice?